# how to assign a selection result to tsquery

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, match

while I run this query

```
SELECT textsearchable_index_col
FROM public.debug_regexfreeflickrfullinfo
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ any(select field_3 from debug_gb):: tsquery;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: tsvector @@ character varying
```

and it is work for without "any" and for just one element:

```
SELECT textsearchable_index_col
FROM public.debug_regexfreeflickrfullinfo
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ ('london'):: tsquery;
```

Answer (score 0):

here the way I solved my problem:

```
SELECT textsearchable_index_col
FROM debug_regexfreeflickrfullinfo
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ any(select (field_3)::tsquery from debug_gb);
```

or either:

```
SELECT title, tags, descriptio
FROM debug_regexfreeflickrfullinfo
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ any(select plainto_tsquery(field_3) from debug_gb);
```